# trying to get device id for google admob, still getting real ads

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm writing an android application and i'm using google admob api for ads.

I was able to add TEST_EMULATOR for the test devices so whenever i use my android emulator
device i see fake ads so i won't have false impressions there. what i'm trying to do now is to add my phone as a test device and I fail.

I tried using 'android device ID' application but none of the numbers there worked.

I tried using the following code to get the device id :

```
final TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();
```

but I still get real impressions.

this is my google adview

```
<com.google.ads.AdView  android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="<UNIT_ID>"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,<NUMBER_I_TRIED>"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                     android:layout_above="@+id/button_endGameExit" />
```

what am i missing?

I know that there are tons of questions regarding this issue, I'm pretty sure i've been through most of them. please any information would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Logcat and you will find a message saying something like: "To get test ads on this device use this identifier: ... ".
I think it will have the tag "Ads" but I'm not certain.